# Changing the name of a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change the reference key from class to Klass. not sure how to do this. I'm assuming that it a quick column rename, but I've never run into changing foreign keys. I'm sure it is simple, but don't want to screw anything up.

```
 class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :schedules, id: false do |t|
      t.references :class, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :student, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [solution in the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference).

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :schedules, id: false do |t|
      t.references :class, index: true, foreign_key: {name: 'by_klass'}
      t.references :student, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Looking at your answer again, I'm not sure whether it is just the name you want to change. So - also have a look at the [`add_foreign_key` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key). You can use the options listed there within the `references` call, in the same way that I've added `name`. I think it may be the `column` option that you are looking for.